# SQL query to list the length of service of the employee in the form n years and m months

Tags: mysql

I have a table named employee the columns are

```
empid,empname,joining date,retiring date  
1,employee,2000-1-1,2010-3-1
```

I have to fetch the length of service of the employee. The output should be as follows:

```
years  months
10      2
```

Comment: See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use MySQL's [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function to obtain the number of whole years and the number of whole months between the joining & retiring dates, then take the latter modulo 12 to get the number of months since the last whole year:

```
SELECT empname,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,  `joining date`, `retiring date`)      AS years,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `joining date`, `retiring date`) % 12 AS months
FROM   employee
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51f29/1/0).